# How to declare dynamic 2D integer array in C++

Tags: c++

I've a requirement where I need to take input from user and based on the input length of array would be decided. For e.g.

```
int row, column;    
cin>> row>>column;    
int matrix[row][column];
```

However `int matrix[row][column]` is not working as compiler is giving an error saying

```
"Expression must have a constant value"
```

Also, if someone can guide me as how address of `matrix[row][column]` assigned to pointer. I know how to do it with static array but not dynamic.

Comment: Use `std::vector<std::vector<int>> matrix;` and `std::vector::resize()`.

Comment: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/matrix.htm, or roll your own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To declare 2d dynamic array you will need pointers of pointers

```
int row, column;    
cin>> row>>column;    
int** matrix = new int*[row];
for(int i = 0; i < row; ++i)
    matrix[i] = new int[column];
```

This is because arrays are static in c++ and take a fixed position in the memory.lets say the array has 1000 element. when you declare a static array this means that there is 1000 positions in the memory after each other reserved for your array. If you want to add one more item to the array you will add this item in the end of the reserved array, but if that position has some data for something other than the array, this data will be deleted!!

but when you declare it as pointers, you don't store the elements nested in the memory, but you are storing them in different locations, and each location is stored in the array of pointers, and when you add new elements to the array, compiler will search for empty locations in the memory and will store the new elements there.

Comment: Thanks Yazan for your reply, this really helps. I was trying something like below and at compile time my program crashed. Please help me understand.

Comment: int mat[2][3]={ {9,10},{11,12}, {13,14} };

 int **ptr={NULL};
 
 ptr[0]=mat[3]; // Program crashes here, please advise what went wrong

Comment: `int mat[3][2]={ {9,10},{11,12}, {13,14} };`
`int **ptr=new int*[3];`
`ptr[0]=mat[0]; `
`ptr[1]=mat[1]; `
`ptr[2]=mat[2]; `
 this is the right declaring of the array(you mixed the 2 and 3 incorrect), and you must declare the pointer as array of pointers

Answer (score 0):

Using a 2D array to hold a matrix is a bad idea - especially because of the loop for memory allocations.
Use a 1D array of size rows * columns and access elements with y * columns+x, and store it inside and unique_ptr to avoid commons memory management problems.

Here's what I propose:

```
uint32_t rows, cols;
std::cin >> rows >> cols; // Check rows and cols are actually numbers
std::unique_ptr<int[]> matrix(new int[rows*cols]);
```

Comment: Just use a `std::vector` as storage. [KISS -- Keep It Simple, Stupid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle). :)

Comment: You don't need to loop for memory allocations if you're willing to do the work to do just one allocation of memory to contain both the pointer array(s) and data.  Filling in the portions of the one chunk of memory with proper address values so they work as pointer arrays can take quite a few lines of code.  It's worth it, though, if you're running a multithreaded app that needs to dynamically allocate and free a lot of 2 or more dimension arrays.  If your app isn't doing that, it's not worth it.